# R is turning large numbers to negative random numbers

Tags: r, import, mat

I am having an issue when importing into R multiple data structures saved as *.mat files by using readMat().

When I read and open the file in R, the content of one single column stored in the data structure changes (apparently) randomly (should be 1504615865460506 and is -1372641510 for example). Also, numbers in the original *.mat file are increasing (1st is 1484649519139343, 2nd is 1484649519142687 etc), while in R corresponding numbers are decreasing (1st is -1372641510, 2nd is -1372633137 etc). No change is occurring on the other variables.

The "wronged" variable is the TimeStamp, a progressive number indicating the exact time a data point was recorded. It is stored into a column, part of a list, part of a even bigger list. It is 'integer' according to class(). 
I read readMat() documentation, though I did not find anything related. In case the problem was the large number, I set options(digits=20), with no effect.

Any ideas/suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

And I attach my code.

```
library(R.matlab)
setwd("C:/Path") 
options(digits=20)
temp = list.files(pattern="*.mat") 
list2env(lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub("*.mat$", "", temp))), readMat), envir = .GlobalEnv) 
rm(temp) 
listAll<-list(mget(ls())) #listAll contains all the *.mat files.



listAll[[1]][[3]] #listAll contains N lists == N of *.mat files.
```

This is an example of the structure of the 3rd list:

```
# $data
# , , 1
# 
# [,1]   
# ID          "A6001"
# TimePoint   "10"   
# MainBuffer  List,12
# TimeBuffer  List,12 #TimeBuffer is the Time Stamp.
```

TimeBuffer contains 12 lists, corresponding to 12 trials. Each trial has 1 column, which is the one that is unwillingly changed in the process.

```
# EventBuffer List,12
# Log         List,12
# 
# 
# attr(,"header")
# attr(,"header")$description
# [1] "MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: MACI64, Created on: Wed Sep 20 16:03:45 2017                                         "
# 
# attr(,"header")$version
# [1] "5"
# 
# attr(,"header")$endian
# [1] "little"

listAll[[1]][[3]][[1]][[4]][[3]][[1]][1,][1]

#[1] 668725504 (and should be 1480500650907453)
```

Comment: 1504615865460506  is outside of R's valid integer range. Check out the `bit64` package which allows you to leverage the additional size of 64-bit integers.

Comment: If it were "just R" altering the values, I would expect it to simply convert them to doubles, rather than integers. The fact that something else odd is happening suggests to me that the code in the R.matlab package is mishandling them in some other specific manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should be 1504615865460506 and is -1372641510 for example

Looks like an overflow error.

From `help(integer)` in R:

> *Note that current implementations of R use 32-bit integers for integer vectors, so the range of representable integers is restricted to about +/-2*10^9: ‘double’s can hold much larger integers exactly.*

So, you'll need to use a larger type such as `double` for the values in question.

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. However, I don't think there is a way of achieving this with readMat (or it is just too much for me). I tried to use another package, rmatio, and repeated the loop with the alternative function read.mat(). Now, the numbers are correct! I have all my 1492686487679232s, of class() 'numeric'.